# Multiple views for controller based on role in application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my application exist a little role system. "Admin" and "normal" users. In my application I display data in tables. An admin must have the possibility to create, edit and delete these data, but the "normal" user must not.

So I thought displaying based on the user different Views would be a good idea. But I am struggleing currently with the implementation.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

if(model.IsAdmin)
{
    ... // get data
}
else
{
    ... // get data, but less, or different
}

    return (model.IsAdmin) ? this.View("AdminView") : this.View("NormalView");

}
```

It could look like this.

1. Is it a good idea to create seperate views on one controller?
2. Should I work with partial views instead and do the logic inside my view to decide which one I want to display? Doesn't seem right.
3. What about the folder structure and file naming? Would be nice if they would both match to MyController/Action/*Index*, instead of .../Index and .../Index2

Thank you and best regards

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: what i am really wondering is the third point. how are the different views organized? i guess in the same folder, but is there any naming convention or something like that? I mean, "adminview" and "normalview" are not the best names, are they?

Comment: Views are already organized in the views folder as per the name of controller in which views are there, If you are asking about the naming convention..it varies as per the organization you are working on.. There is no such hard coded rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
Most certain this is not a good practice.

You should try to create different Controllers for each Role. Or you could user Areas to point to admin.

If you just load a different view, the guest user could still introduce in the url bar something like "/admin/deleteSmth/1", and do admin actions.

The best it would be if you would implement different controllers or areas.

2. You should keep the logic far away from views. View are made only to render data. That should be all. All the logic should be made higher than the controller, if you have a business logic layer.
3. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/601504/Using-areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC-to-organize-a-project . Areas, use them.

Comment: thank you very much. i like this. i will give areas a try. :) may i ask you antother question? how would you handle authorization using digest authentication? i am currently getting the name through User.Identity.Name, look it up in the database. but i am pretty sure that this is very bad. but i don't know how to handle it correctly. you also mentioned already that the "normal" user could still perform /admin/delete/1 if he tried. i am new to all this and wanna learn how to.

Comment: I haven't worked with DigestAuthentication, but you must use this type of authentication? MVC4 has a simple and clean way to deal with authentication, you should give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this could be

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

if(model.IsAdmin)
{
    ... // get data
return view("AdminView")
}
else
{
    ... // get data, but less, or different
return view("NormalView")
}
//no need to perform extra checks
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. i am aware of that. is there a more elegant solution for this. this just feels not right, or is my feeling tricking me?

Comment: there are more ways to do so..but can't give you exact solution until and unless you tell me what exactly you want to do..